# Emacs search/replace macro on single line triple quoted docstrings

Tags: regex, emacs

I want to find all instances of triple quoted single-line docstrings:

```
def foo(bar):
    """Frobnicate bar."""
    ...
```

and place the trailing triple quote on a new line:

```
def foo(bar):
    """Frobnicate bar.
    """
    ...
```

i.e. with the second set of quotes on its own line (the triple quotes can also be spelled `'''...'''`.

I'm having trouble with grouping parens, i.e.

```
(defun single-line-tqstring ()
 (interactive)
 (re-search-forward
  "^ +\"\"\".*\"\"\"$"))
```

will find the next instance of a single line triple quoted string. To account for the different quotes and to save the indentation I need to create some groups, however this doesn't find anything:

```
(defun single-line-tqstring ()
 (interactive)
 (re-search-forward
  "^\( +\)\([\"']\{3\}\).*\2$"))
```

`single-line-tqstring: Search failed: "^( +)([\"']{3}).*^B$"`

Have I completely misunderstood the syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I've found a solution

```
(defun fix-single-line-tqstring ()
 (interactive)
 (replace-regexp
  "^\\( +\\)\\([\"']\\{3\\}\\)\\([^\n]*\\)\\2$"
  "\\1\\2\\3\n\\1\\2"))
```

although the backslashes are a bit blinding... (I'm sure there must be better ways of doing this..?)